# Routing issue - URL rewriting middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to configure my asp.net core web application for this routing. When I click other pages, it goes to [www.xyx.com/page1](https://xyx.com/page1) instead of [www.xyx.com/admin/abc/page1](https://www.xyx.com/admin/abc/page1)

If I manually change the URL to [www.xyx.com/admin/abc/page1](http://www.xyx.com/admin/abc/page1), yes I can see page1 loaded correctly.

I am using .NET 6 and this is my program.cs

```
var app = builder.Build();

app.UsePathBase("/admin/abc");

var options = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRewrite(@"^admin/abc/(.*)", @"admin/abc/$1", true);
app.UseRewriter(options);

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.Headers.Remove("X-Forwarded-Proto");
    context.Request.Headers.Add("X-Forwarded-Proto", "https");
    context.Request.Scheme = "https";
    await next.Invoke();
});
app.UseForwardedHeaders();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
```

Comment: Do you want all the `www.xyx.com/*` route rewrite to `www.xyx.com/admin/abc/*` ?

Comment: yes ,  all pages to be rerouted to  www.xyx.com/admin/abc/*

Comment: Your regular expression captures only what's starting with admin/abc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it fixed with these configuration.

```
app.UsePathBase("/admin/abc");

... 

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();

    endpoints.MapGet("/{**path}", async context =>
    {
        string path = context.Request.Path.Value.TrimStart('/');
        context.Response.Redirect($"/{path}");
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    });
});
```

And in the Layout.cshtml:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

@{
    var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
    var hrefPath = "";

    if (HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host.Equals("localhost"))
    {
        hrefPath = "";
    }
    else
    {
        switch (environment)
        {
            case "Development":
                hrefPath = "/admin/abc";
                break;

            default:
                hrefPath = "";
                break;
        }
    }
}

<a href="@hrefPath/Dropdown" class="nav-link">
    <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
    <p>Dropdowns</p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following rewrite URL, after the first one you wrote I guess

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRewrite(@"^admin/abc/(.*)", @"admin/abc/$1", true)
    .AddRewrite(@"^(.*)", @"admin/abc/$1", true);
```

You might consider to get rid of this line of code if you want it to work

```
app.UsePathBase("/admin/abc");
```

Comment: I tried your code but error. No webpage was found for the web address: https://www.xyx.com/admin/abc/
HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: @Steve It's strange, it works on my side ^^' what url did you check ?

Comment: After I removed `app.UsePathBase("/admin/abc");`, still had the same error. When I run locally, also same error

Comment: @Steve If you remove all rewrites, what is the result when you put https://xyx.com/admin/abc in your browser ?

Comment: If I just use this code, it works. xyx.com/admin/abc => xyx.com/admin/abc/index. But if I click any other link to other pages, it will go to xyx.com/page1. `app.UsePathBase("/admin/cmdb");

var options = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRewrite(@"^admin/cmdb/(.*)", @"admin/cmdb/$1", true);


app.UseRewriter(options);`

Comment: @Steve Maybe the click on the link bypass the rewrite mechanism, what happens if you put manually the url https://xyx.com/test in your browser ? is this rewritten to https://xyx.com/admin/abc/test ?

Comment: When I put xyx.com/test, it is the same. It will go to xyx.com/test

Answer (score 0):

From the examples in the comments, I think you want a **redirect**, not a rewrite.

In which case, you want the following.

```cs
var options = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRedirect("^(?!admin/abc)(.*)$", "admin/abc/$1");

app.UseRewriter(options);
```

Match all routes that don't start with `admin/abc` (to prevent a redirect loop) and redirect to `admin/abc/<rest-of-the-url>`

Comment: When I put https://xyx.com/admin/abc, it goes to https://xyx.com/admin/abc/admin/abc

Comment: Is this the real URL? Since none of these regexes work for you, I'm thinking there's a rogue character we're not accounting for